# View mailing in browser- access denied

Tags: civimail, mosaico

CiviCRM 5.3 (at the moment), Drupal 7.63 Mosaico Ext- 2.0-beta4.1528762072

View Mailing as browser link from emails working fine for logged in users, not for anon

Given view public mailing content prmission to all users. Flushed Civi and drupal caches

Still no access for anon users (yup, it's set as public pages)

Only new factor for me here is the mosaico extension. Anyone else had similar issues? know where else I can look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out clicking Save when you change permissions **really** helps.

Craig

Comment: Not working for me.